# Can't debug nodejs express application in Visual Studio Code when using clustered child processes

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug my nodejs express application using Visual Studio Code's debugger. The debugger technically works, but for some reason the code stops executing early when ran via the debugger. Here's the code for my `index.js` file:

```
'use strict';

var config = require('./config/config');
var logger = require('./lib/logger');
var errors = require('./lib/errors');
var throng = require('throng');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var mongoose = require('mongoose').connect(config.mongo_url);
mongoose.Promise = Promise;
// mongoose.set('debug', true);

var api = require('./app/api/api');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var options = {
    workers: config.web_concurrency,
    lifetime: Infinity
}

throng(options, start);

function start() {

    // middleware
    app.set('x-powered-by', false);
    app.use(require('morgan')('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    // routes
    app.use('/api/' + config.api_version, api);

    // errors
    app.use(errors);

    // Server setup
    var server = app.listen(config.port, function() {
        console.log('server server server');
        logger.silly('pid: ' + process.pid + ' listening on port:' + config.port);
    });

    // Shutdown
    var gracefulShutdown = function() {
        logger.silly('Received SIGTERM signal, shutting down express server');
        server.close();
    }

    process.on('SIGTERM', gracefulShutdown);

    server.on('close', function() {
        logger.silly('Express server closed.. about to cleanup connections');

        mongoose.disconnect();
    });
}
```

This is a very basic and typical `index.js` file that I have successfully used across many different projects for quite some time now. When I run `node index.js`, `nodemon index.js`, or `npm start` via terminal, this all works fine. The application runs and I can successfully send API requests to the app.

However, when I run this using Visual Studio Code's debugger, it stops at the following line of code:

```
throng(options, start);
```

I can set breakpoints before this point and they will hit, and I can also see log statements before this line in the terminal window of VSCode as well. However, after `throng(options, start)` runs, nothing happens. I can't send http requests to the app either. VSCode's debug console just gives me the typical output you'd expect like this:

```
node --debug-brk=11591 --nolazy index.js 
Debugger listening on port 11591
Debugger listening on port 11592
```

The `throng` module is an easy way to fork child processes in your nodejs apps: https://github.com/hunterloftis/throng

No matter what I do this all works fine when I run it via terminal, but it just won't work when using VSCode's debugger.

Here is my `launch.json` file that was generated by VSCode:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/index.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "port": 3000
        }
    ]
}
```